# JSON Schema object properties defined by enum

Tags: json, jsonschema

I'm attempting to reuse an enum in my JSON Schema to define the properties for an object.

I was wondering if the following is correct.

**JSON Schema**

```json
{
  "type": "object",
  "propertyNames": {
    "enum": ["Foo","Bar"]
  },
  "patternProperties": {
    ".*": {
      "type": "number"
    }
  }
}
```

**JSON Data**

```json
{
    "Foo": 123,
    "Bar": 456
}
```

The reason I ask is that I get inconsistent results from JSON Schema validation libraries. Some indicate the JSON validates, while others indicate the JSON is invalid.

*p.s. if anyone is wondering "why" I'm trying to define the properties with an enum, it is because the enum is shared in various parts of my json schema. In some cases it is a constraint on a string, but I need the identical set of possible values both on those string properties and also on the object properties. As an enum I can maintain the set of possible values in one place.*

Comment: The doc says any schema is allowed in `propertyNames` with the `type` being implicitly set to `string`. So I assume your approach is correct. Can you share which validators fail?  `propertyNames` only came with draft 6 so maybe some of your validators don't support it yet?

Comment: Ajv failed with the exact schema above.  But oddly a more complex schema that used a similar pattern, the only difference was enum was a $ref.  Several online JSON Schema validators I tried also failed.

Comment: I quickly through together an example with `$ref`: [jsonschemavalidator.net example](https://www.jsonschemavalidator.net/s/7W8eTDL9) which works as expected. Can you add your failing example with the `$ref` to your question>

Comment: Your JSON Schema is valid and correct. What do you mean by "failed"? I wonder if "strict mode" is causing a problem here.

Comment: It works on this playground https://jsonschema.dev/s/LzqY9 using a non-current version of ajv.

Comment: Ajv actually worked, I had used the API wrong. I will have to find the specific validators that failed and will share them.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, that's a valid JSON Schema. You could also express it like this:

```json
{
  "type": "object",
  "propertyNames": {
    "enum": ["Foo","Bar"]
  },
  "additionalProperties": {
    "type": "number"
  }
}
```

It says "all property names must conform to this schema: (one of these values listed in the enum); also, all property values must conform to this schema: (must be numeric type)."

What errors do you get from the implementations that report this as invalid? Those implementations have a bug; would you consider reporting it to them?

Comment: That use of `additionalProperties` is incorrect and in fact invalid JSON schema. The JSON Schema spec says `additionalProperties` must be a boolean or an Object.

Further, the purpose of `additionalProperties` is to define constraints on properties that are NOT defined in the schema. 

In my actual schema, I use `"additionalProperties": false` and `patternProperties` to define the type for the properties defined by the enum.

Comment: Also, per your suggestion about reporting bug to any json schema validator that fails, I definitely will do that.

Comment: The schema is correct. I used `additionalProperties` as a schema object.  And `additionalProperties` will check everything -- it doesn't skip the properties defined by `propertyNames`.